# Android Camera2 Wrong Rotation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-camera

I'm trying to implement **android.hardware.camera2**, but I'm a little bit confused with it.

The camera is rotating with the phone.

BEFORE Taking the picture, If I rotated the phone the camera is rotating instead of keeping the same position.

Example image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpXms.jpg).

I don't know why it happens. I don't have two layouts for the holder.

Camera XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Camera" >

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_foto"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#FFFF56B9"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#FFD5379B"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_switchcam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_switch"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#267300"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#1e5b00"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Camera Activity:

```java
public class AppCamera extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
    private static int cam = 0;

    private FloatingActionButton mBtnShot;
    private FloatingActionButton mBtnSwitch;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        mTextureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);

        mBtnShot = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture);
        mBtnSwitch = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_switchcam);

        mBtnShot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }

        });

        mBtnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cam == 0) {
                    cam = 1;
                } else {
                    cam = 0;
                }
                if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                    mCameraDevice.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }
                openCamera();
            }

        });

    }

    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());

            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics
                        .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }

            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM", "teste.jpg");

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPicture");
            thread.start();
            final Handler backgroudHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroudHandler);

            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(AppCamera.this, "Saved:"+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startPreview();
                }

            };

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, backgroudHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            }, backgroudHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void openCamera() {

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[cam];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener(){

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface,
                                                int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
        }

    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {

            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }

    protected void startPreview() {

        if(null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }

        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if(null == texture) {
            return;
        }

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        try {
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    Toast.makeText(AppCamera.this, "onConfigureFailed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updatePreview() {

        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
        }

        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

        try {
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue? Any solution?

Comment: Nope, just deleted the Project and go on xD

Comment: @ShylendraMadda have you solved this issue if so please let me know im trying my best but i couldnt solve it. thanks in advance

Comment: Nope I didn't find it @AmareshJana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height)" is fired, call the following method:

```
/**
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
     * setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
```

For more info, have a look to the following file:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

Comment: What could be the `mPreviewSize`?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda I just used Size from java.util

Comment: I also used the `android.util.Size`

Comment: Okay thanks for the update.. me too used same yesterday..;P

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }
```

Comment: Gonna test it, I'll let you know!

Comment: Doesn't work. The code above is for rotate the Picture after print, I'm with a inssue happening before taking the Picture.

Answer (score 1):

in which I finish the problem, I visualize it well, the problem is that the saved image rotates it to the left